# Splunk: How to implement "max(Index) by Version"

Tags: splunk

I have "version" and "Index" variables

"Version" contains values like: 150,160,170...
"Index" contains values like: 1,2,3,4,5

Basically I want to know if there's an implementation for this kind of condition:

max(Index) by Version

Meaning for the below 6 events:
150 , 5
140 , 1
140 , 2
130 , 1
130 , 2
130 , 3
Ill get only those 3:
150 , 5
140 , 2
130 , 3
Because it has only the highest index **for every version**

Thanks!

Couldn't implement this from Splunk documentation:

Aggregation

`max([by=<grp>])`

When you call `max(by=<grp>)`, it returns one maximum for each value of the property or properties specified by `<grp>`. For example, if the input stream contains 5 different values for the property named `datacenter`, `max(by='datacenter')` outputs 5 maximums.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `stats` command to find the maximum Index value for each Version.

```
| stats max(Index) by Version
```

Answer (score 0):

> Basically I want to know if there's an implementation for this kind of condition:

> max(Index) by Version

What you're asking for seem to be precisely how you would call `max` with [`stats`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/stats):

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp Version=* datacenter=*
| stats max(Version) by datacenter
```

Does that not do what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys!
Eventually what was the trick was "eventstats", because I wanted the highest index for each event